# asterisk outbound calls and inbound calls fom different domains

Tags: sip, asterisk, outbound, inbound

How can I configure asterisk (sip client) for outbound calls to other sip clients that are registered to sip servers(domains) different from my sip domain? What about inbound calls from  sip clients registered to different sip servers(domains) than the domain I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like

Dial(SIP/username@domain) for most of public domain.

Unfortanly no any way to do call from thoose domain to ur domain. unless admin of that domain do setup call route.